# Why are packets taking 64 hops to connect from my laptop to my laptop?

Tags: ping, connection, packet, icmp

So, I'm pinging my laptop (from my laptop) expecting the TLL in the reports to be 128 (Because I'm on Windows 10), but I get this instead:

```
Pinging [REDACTED] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from [REDACTED]: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from [REDACTED]: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from [REDACTED]: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from [REDACTED]: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for [REDACTED]:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 3ms, Average = 2ms
```

128 - 64 = 64 hops were made

I don't understand why this is happening.

Also, when I use my host name (or link-local IPv6 address) I get this:

```
Pinging [REDACTED] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from [REDACTED]: time<1ms
Reply from [REDACTED]: time<1ms
Reply from [REDACTED]: time<1ms
Reply from [REDACTED]: time<1ms

Ping statistics for [REDACTED]:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

And when I use my private IP address:

```
Pinging [REDACTED] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from [REDACTED]: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from [REDACTED]: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from [REDACTED]: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from [REDACTED]: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for [REDACTED]:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: Please add the ping commands that you used to your examples.

Comment: idk why, but if you ping (myaddress) you always get 64, if you ping 127.0.0.1 you get 128. (btw, there's no need to redact your internal IP address)

Comment: "pinging my laptop (from my laptop)" possibly you are pinging your public IP address (instead of some local address), which is why everything gets routed through your ISP first. But you've left out all information to determine if this is the case, or not. Like actual IP addresses, your local network configuration, your local network setup ...

Comment: @harrymc it's just 'ping [REDACTED]'. No extra arguments

Comment: @dirkt It is my public IP address! Please post this comment as an answer so I can approve it

Comment: What is REDACTED? IP internal or external, host name, or else?

Comment: @CrabbyFish Is [REDACTED] the local ip address on your local LAN (something like 192.168.x.x) or a public ip-address. There is no point in hiding a LAN ip-address anyway, but it makes a big difference for understanding your question.

Comment: @harrymc in the first one, it's my public IP, in the second one, It's my host name, in the third one, it's my local/private IP

Comment: @CrabbyFish Now it is clear. Initially you gave no indication what was what. It is clear one was localhost, but not what the other 2 where about. And that makes all the difference to answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> pinging my laptop (from my laptop)

Possibly you are pinging your public IP address (instead of some local address), which is why everything gets routed through your ISP first.

In particular for the link-local address, and any other IP addresses that are local to your (home) network, this doesn't happen.

Hence the difference.